# copying two vectors java

Tags: java, vector, copy

I was trying to compile the following lines of code and got errors:

```
  public class c
  {
   vector<a> variables;
   void create_c(Vector<a> l)
   {    
     Vector<a> variables = new Vector<a>();
     variables.setSize(l.size()); // so that variables has enough capacity to store l
     /*variables= l.clone();*/
     Collections.copy(variables, l);
    }

   }
```

I'm trying to copy the contents of one vector to another by using the clone() method or Collections.copy() method.
the  in vector  is actually another class having its own methods and variables.

```
 public class a
 {

 int a;
 void add_a(int y)
 {
 a=y;
 }

 }
```

While most people have suggested using Arraylist(), I'd like to implement this using Vector too and check for performance. So, I'd be happy if someone could give me a solution involving vectors.

The problem with the code is I'm getting an error saying 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Vector' at Collections.copy(variables,l). If I comment out the Collections.copy() and try it with the clone() statement in the next line, I'm getting the same error.

I must also mention that I class a is a public class having its own file in the same package.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You need to google and learn some of **Java Naming Convention**.

Comment: Maybe not related, but the declaration of 'variables' inside of class 'c' should have a capital V for Vector.

Comment: Use ArrayList and if you want it synchronized use Collections.synchronizedList(List).

Comment: Would you OK if it could be done by a loop? By copying index by index or You emphasizing that You have to use Collections#copy function

Comment: Why did you declare twice `Vector variables` twice?

Comment: What is it with newbies and `Vectors`!? They were practically deprecated years ago.

Comment: @bhesh gurung.. Well, this is for an academic thing and everyone uses these forums, so I had to be vague about naming the variables.. I'm sorry about that.. will try to be clearer in the future..

Comment: @Learner.. I don't want to do it in a loop when there's a built in function already there.. I declared the variables twice ..because the first one was just that.. a declaration.. i plan to add more methods into the class.. im adding elements in the vector in that function alone so i used 'new' to allocate space for it.. i didnt want it to create a vector everytime the class was called.

Comment: @Bohemian.. I'm under the impression that I can't resize (increase) arraylists to the size i want .. there's no builtin function for that.. so i prefer to use vectors.. correct me if im wrong..

Comment: You are correct, but why do you care? Why do you want to set the size? In real life (ie production code), nobody (and I mean *nobody*) uses Vector. Everyone uses ArrayList and lets the implementation manage the size. Originally, Vector was supposed to provide a threadsafe implementation of List, but it was not in fact threadsafe and remains a broken class in this respect, which is the main reason nobody uses it. It carries the performance overhead of a threadsafe implementation but is not threadsafe - it's a "lose lose" situation. My advice is to forget that Vector exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to take care of the following things

- The compilation error with `variables= l.clone()` can be solved by casting to your Vector. Like this `variables = (Vector<a>)l.clone()` (btw, ignore the typecast warning)
- The given code `Collections.copy(variables, l);` compiles just fine, without any errors
- Try to use `Java Naming Conventions` always

The `Collections.copy()` gives you a shallow copy of your collection. Use the following example to make a deep copy of your collection.

- Here the class that being copied should implement `Cloneable` interface and override the `clone` method
- Iterate over the original collection and add the cloned objects to the target collection
- the `createCopy` function returns the deep-copied collection
- Notice the difference in memory locations of the copied and original vectors in the print statements in the console

The `TestCopy` class

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Vector;

public class TestCopy {

    private Vector<ClassToCopy> createCopy(Vector<ClassToCopy> classToCopy) {
        Vector<ClassToCopy> localVariable = new Vector<ClassToCopy>();
        for(ClassToCopy classVar:classToCopy)
            try {
                localVariable.add((ClassToCopy)classVar.clone());
            } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return localVariable;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vector<ClassToCopy> originalVector = new Vector<ClassToCopy>();

        TestCopy testCopy = new TestCopy();
        originalVector.add(new ClassToCopy(1));
        originalVector.add(new ClassToCopy(2));
        originalVector.add(new ClassToCopy(3));
        originalVector.add(new ClassToCopy(4));
        System.out.println(originalVector);

        Vector<ClassToCopy> copiedVector = testCopy.createCopy(originalVector);
        System.out.println(copiedVector);

    }

}
```

The `ClassToCopy` class

```
package com.test;

public class ClassToCopy implements Cloneable {

    private int varA;

    /**
     * Constructor for ClassToCopy.
     * @param varA <tt></tt>
     */
    public ClassToCopy() {
        this(-1);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for ClassToCopy.
     * @param varA <tt></tt>
     */
    public ClassToCopy(int varA) {
        super();
        this.varA = varA;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the varA.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the varA.</tt>
     */
    public int getVarA() {
        return varA;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the varA.
     *
     * @param varA <tt> the varA to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setVarA(int varA) {
        this.varA = varA;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassToCopy : "+super.toString()+" [varA=" + varA + "]";
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#clone()
     */
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.clone();
    }

}
```

The output i got

```
[ClassToCopy : com.test.ClassToCopy@19821f [varA=1], ClassToCopy : com.test.ClassToCopy@addbf1 [varA=2], ClassToCopy : com.test.ClassToCopy@42e816 [varA=3], ClassToCopy : com.test.ClassToCopy@9304b1 [varA=4]]
[ClassToCopy : com.test.ClassToCopy@190d11 [varA=1], ClassToCopy : com.test.ClassToCopy@a90653 [varA=2], ClassToCopy : com.test.ClassToCopy@de6ced [varA=3], ClassToCopy : com.test.ClassToCopy@c17164 [varA=4]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort!! I wasn't even aware of it. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Hi Floose try the following. It is working .

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

public class VectorCopyTest {

Vector<String> variables;

   void create_c(Vector l)
   {    
     Vector<String> variables = new Vector<String>();
     variables.setSize(l.size()); // so that variables has enough capacity to store l
     /*variables= l.clone();*/
     Collections.copy(variables, l);
     System.out.println(variables.size());
    }

   public static void main(String a[]){
       Vector<String> variables1 = new Vector<String>();
       variables1.addElement("hi");
       variables1.addElement("hello");
       VectorCopyTest copyTest = new VectorCopyTest();
       copyTest.create_c(variables1);
   }
```

}

Comment: Thanks! But could you tell me what's wrong with my original code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector newVector = (Vector) oldVector.clone();
```

Above code simply works for deep copying a vector.